# installing GEOS on ubuntu

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, wget, geos

hi i am trying to install GEOS on ubuntu with

```
wget https://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-X.Y.Z.tar.bz2
```

but it gives

```
--2021-03-10 10:48:18--  https://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-X.Y.Z.tar.bz2
Resolving download.osgeo.org (download.osgeo.org)... 140.211.15.30
Connecting to download.osgeo.org (download.osgeo.org)|140.211.15.30|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-03-10 10:48:19 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

judging from the HTTP reponse i dont think it actually downloaded so is there another way to download GEOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify which GEOS version you want.

> geos-X.Y.Z to geos-1.0.0

```
wget https://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-1.0.0.tar.bz2
```

GEOS version list https://download.osgeo.org/geos/